# How can check and select available date in selenium

Tags: java, angular, selenium

There is inspect code and this web site using angular application for front end. How can I select date. If all date disable then go to next month and check if not available then go to next month

**HTML :**

```
<div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
</div>
</td>
<td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-06">
   <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">6</a></div>
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
   </div>
</td>
<td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-07">
   <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">7</a></div>
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
   </div>
</td>
<td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-08">
   <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">8</a></div>
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
   </div>
</td>
<td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-09">
   <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">9</a></div>
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
   </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-10">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">10</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-11">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">11</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-12">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">12</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-13">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">13</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-14">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">14</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-15">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">15</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-16">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">16</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-17">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">17</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-18">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">18</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-19">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">19</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-20">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">20</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-21">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">21</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-22">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">22</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-23">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">23</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-24">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">24</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-25">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">25</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-26">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">26</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-27">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">27</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-future date-availiable" data-date="2022-01-28">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">28</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-event-harness" style="margin-top: 0px;">
               <a class="fc-daygrid-event fc-daygrid-block-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-event-start fc-event-end fc-event-future availiable">
                  <div class="fc-event-main">
                     <div class="fc-event-main-frame">
                        <div class="fc-event-title-container">
                           <div class="fc-event-title fc-sticky">availiable</div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </a>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-29">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">29</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-future" data-date="2022-01-30">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-top"><a class="fc-daygrid-day-number">30</a></div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-mon fc-day-disabled">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-tue fc-day-disabled">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-wed fc-day-disabled">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-thu fc-day-disabled">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-fri fc-day-disabled">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sat fc-day-disabled">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
            <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bg"></div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="fc-daygrid-day fc-day fc-day-sun fc-day-disabled">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-frame fc-scrollgrid-sync-inner">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-events">
      <div class="fc-daygrid-day-bottom" style="margin-top: 0px;"></div>
```

Here is date picker [image: Attched]

when date available then click first one other wise go to next month and check if find any available date then click.

how can I do that help me I tried but I couldn't

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you select elements using XPath and check their CSS style that disables the element.
For example "pointer-events" is set to the "none" value instead of "auto" or some CSS class that disables and changes the element's behavior.
If you've found this kind of element then you should click on it otherwise, you should select the element that corresponds to the "next month" reference and click it instead, starting to search for the clickable day elements again.
I hope that will be helpful.